# get back deleted record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i am in big trouble now.
by mistake i was deleted the (some thing around 2,00,000) record from remote server(SQL 2008) table.
is there any way,so i can get back this record.

please help,

thank you

additional
*Server not granting me to access the backup file on server side.

Comment: How deleted with truncate or delete command?

Comment: may be post here?   http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: **you are in big trouble now!** +1 vote for good question! there is a way for shure... maybe make a backup and try with some file recovery on db files! :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Restore it from the back-up database.

Comment: i have backup but its on server's "D" drive and server not granting me access for it.how i can? :(((

Comment: @gofor.net - Thats good to know that backup is available. You just inform your seniors and get a copy of that DB. Then you can get the missing data from the backup db. Dont think you will have persmissions to do that by yourself.

Comment: hmm...thank you for u r instant reply.but is there any tool which can read the transaction log.so i can find anything needed?

Answer (score 4):

for a quick fix, assuming no FK issues or a cascading delete:

1) restore backup to new database
2) in the database with the deleted data, run something like this:

```
INSERT INTO schema.YourTable
        (colA, colB, colC)
    SELECT
        colA, colB, colC
        FROM server.RESTORED_Database.schema.YourTable
```

if the table has an identity column use: [SET IDENTITY_INSERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)